# Maintain the order of elements while using list.append

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to look for substrings in the elements of a list. I wanted to search for these substrings in a specific order and append the answers to an empty list maintaining that order.

```
mylist = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789', 'ABC987', 'aBc654']
sub = 'abc'
sub1 = 'def'
newlist=[]
for s in mylist:
    if sub1 in s:
        newlist.append(s)
    if sub in s:
        newlist.append(s)
newlist
```

The result I get is ['abc123', 'def456']. The expected output should be ['def456', 'abc123']. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first loop iteration with `mylist`, s="abc123"

It hits the first `if`, which evaluates `False`. It hits the second `if`, evaluates `True` and appends the value.

On the second loop iteration, s="def456"

It hits the first `if` => `True`, it hits the second `if` => `False`

You could always use two loops instead:

```py
mylist = ['abc123', 'def456', 'ghi789', 'ABC987', 'aBc654']
sub = 'abc'
sub1 = 'def'
newlist=[]
for s in mylist:
    if sub in s:
        newlist.append(s)
for s in mylist:
    if sub1 in s:
        newlist.append(s)
```